# Hive Query Fail with Error The number of tasks for this job 31497 exceeds the configured limit 30000

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a hive query on a table which has 2250 partitions, I am getting this error, I am not sure which tasks is it exceeding and how do I fix this. Thanks,

Hive history file=/tmp/hadoop/hive_job_log_hadoop_201310040052_1692176679.txt
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 10
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: The number of tasks for this job 31497 exceeds the configured limit 30000
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3943)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The number of tasks for this job 31497 exceeds the configured limit 30000
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.checkTaskLimits(JobInProgress.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.(JobInProgress.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3941)
    ... 10 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property **mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job** in your **mapred-site.xml** and set it to a value higher than 31497 or whatever is your requirement. **Restart** the daemons after making the change.